# Rotator Control asp.net to show ads in it

Tags: javascript, asp.net

[image: Near By]

i need to make control in asp.net like in the image, which control can i use 
or if there is useful links

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done out of the box from ASP.NET. You need to look into a client-side javascript component that does that.